# Custom parallax scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I have a custom parallax scrolling section of a site. There are speech bubbles in various places and they all scroll at different speeds.

http://goo.gl/jZhVrJ (you will find the speech bubbles half way down the page)

When you scroll down the first time, it all works fine and the elements are positioned where I would like them. Here is a screenshot of how it should look:

[image]

However, if you scroll back to the top, then back down again - the positioning of the bubbles is different every time you go back to that section. If you do it enough times you can get the speech bubbles completely outside that block of content. Here is a screenshot of it eventually not looking right: 
[image]

The general concept here is that I have positioned each of the speech bubbles. Then, as the user scrolls the code changes the 'top' property for each bubble. If the user is scrolling down, it reduces the 'top' value. If they are scroll up, it increases the 'top' value. Each bubble is a different magnifier so the bubbles appear to be moving at different speeds.

This also uses the "inview" plugin so the scrolling only happens while the user has that block in view.

Here is the JS code doing the parallax scrolling:

```
var $window = $(window);
var windowHeight = $window.height();
var $quoteBG = $('.philosophy');
var quote1 = $("#quote1");
var quote2 = $("#quote2");
var quote3 = $("#quote3");
var quote4 = $("#quote4");
var quote5 = $("#quote5");
var quote6 = $("#quote6");
var quote7 = $("#quote7");
var quote8 = $("#quote8");
var quote9 = $("#quote9");

var scrolldirection = '-';
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var modifier = '-';
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       scrolldirection = 'down';
   } else {
      scrolldirection = 'up';
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});

//function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
function Move(){ 

    //if the second section is in view...
    if($quoteBG.hasClass("inview")){

        if ( scrolldirection == 'down' ) {
            modifier = '-';
        } else {
            modifier = '+';
        }

        quote1.css( 'top', modifier+'=2');
        quote2.css( 'top', modifier+'=1');
        quote3.css( 'top', modifier+'=3');
        quote4.css( 'top', modifier+'=2.1');
        quote5.css( 'top', modifier+'=2.5');
        quote6.css( 'top', modifier+'=3');
        quote7.css( 'top', modifier+'=2');
        quote8.css( 'top', modifier+'=1.5');
        quote9.css( 'top', modifier+'=3');

    }
}

$window.resize(function(){ //if the user resizes the window...
    Move(); //move the background images in relation to the movement of the scrollbar
});        

$window.bind('scroll', function(){ //when the user is scrolling...
    Move(); //move the background images in relation to the movement of the scrollbar
});
```

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe on the link that you provided. Would it be possible for you to create a JSFiddle or something similar that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I can't get this to work in JSFiddle, seems too complex for me to recreate. 

You do have to scroll down and back to the top several times. To get it to look like the screenshot where it is severely broken I went down and back up about 25 times.

Comment: Nevermind, got a functional (dysfunctional?) JSFiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/up15ns6t/

Comment: I have also noticed that the faster you switch from scrolling up to down to up etc the more it exaggerates the wrong positioning. So maybe there is an issue in determining the scroll direction - like some kind of delay that happens when you switch real fast and as a result it doesn't start decreasing the 'top' position for a few ms and as a result it starts getting of course.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following code to your fiddle to get it working:

```
$quoteBG.on('inview', function (evt, isInView) {
    if (isInView) {
        $quoteBG.addClass("inview");
    }
    else {
        $quoteBG.removeClass("inview");
    }
});
```

The fixed version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/up15ns6t/2/

After playing with it, I see a couple issues.

First issue is what I suspected from the start: your position calculations are done by adding or subtracting a fixed amount each time a scroll event fires. The problem with this is that you are making the same adjustment regardless of how far the window was scrolled. For example, you are adjusting the first quote by 2 px when the window scrolls 1 pixel between events and when it scrolls 100 pixels between events. This makes the results non-deterministic.

If I were doing it, I'd try to come up with a deterministic algorithm that calculates the position of each quote based on the scroll position of the window. Alternatively, you could try using your add/subtract approach, but include in your calculations the amount that the window has scrolled since the last event.

The other thing I noticed while playing with it is that the position doesn't get updated when the parent div (`.philosophy`) gets hidden. So if you keep scrolling it in and out of view, the quotes gradually creep up. This behavior is caused by this line of code:

```
if($quoteBG.hasClass("inview")){
```

You would need to include an "or was previously in view" case to that logic.

I don't have more time to play with it and come up with a working version at the moment, but maybe you can use these ideas to get it working.

**Update 1**
I created a simple deterministic algorithm in your fiddle and applied it to a single quote div to keep things from getting too confusing. It first calculates the amount of the background div that is visible:

```
var windowHeight = $window.height();
var backgroundTop = Math.round($quoteBG.offset().top);
var st = $window.scrollTop();
var visibleHeight = (windowHeight + st) - backgroundTop;
```

The `visibleHeight` value will be negative if the background div is below the bottom of the view port. Once that becomes positive, I calculate the new position for the quote div based on that.

On page load, I recorded the initial position of the quote div and defined a motion ratio for it:

```
var motion1 = 0.5;
var baseTop1 = $quote1.position().top;
```

When scrolling, I use these combined with the `visibleHeight` to calculate the position for the quote:

```
var position1 = baseTop1 + Math.round(visibleHeight * motion1)
```

So in this example, the quote scrolls down at half the speed of the background (due to `motion1 = 0.5`).

The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/up15ns6t/5/

One thing to note is that the position calculation does not handle the case where the quote goes off the bottom of the background. If you wanted to put something below it, you might need to add some checking to prevent the quote from moving too far down.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I tried using what you provided but ultimately couldn't figure anything out. "deterministic algorithm" is way beyond me, I have no idea what that meant. As for the "or was previously in view", it doesn't make sense why that matters. If the .philosophy div is not visible, the "inview" class is removed. If that .philosophy div doesn't have the "inview" class, it is not supposed to add/subtract anything. I will just continue my search for some premade library, this just appears to be beyond my JS abilities.

Comment: "Deterministic" just means that it always gives the same output for a given input. Your current algorithm does not do that. Regarding the in-view issue, are you familiar with the developer tools built into most browsers? I noticed that behavior because I was watching the attributes on the `.philosopy` div in the DOM inspector as I scrolled the page.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at CSS-only paralax: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ and http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

Comment: I looked for hours last night but everything does parallax only on backgrounds, not on actual elements. The background for each of those quote bubbles is the same, I just want the bubbles themselves to scroll at different speeds. Still not clear on what you mean for deterministic or the inview issue - as far as my understanding, the code should just work but clearly it's not. I am very familiar with dev tools, I use console.log all the time. Maybe it is my understanding of how the on scroll event works that is causing the problem, but as I understand it that it fires for every pixel scrolled.

Comment: The scroll event does not fire once for every pixel scrolled, it fires for every user action that causes the page to scroll (mouse wheel, dragging the thumb, clicking the scrollbar arrows, etc.). The number of pixels scrolled can vary widely between calls to the event handler, depending on the user action.